# Xamarin iOS UISlider as AVPlayer Progressbar

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, avplayer, uislider, audio-player

How to use UISlider with AVPlayer to show the progress of the audio file that is being played in Xamarin iOS? I am using AVPlayer to play the audio file which works fine. Now, I want to connect the AVPlayer with UISlider to show the progress of AVPlayer as it plays the audio file.

Thanks in advance.